# Image zoom transition android

Tags: android, animation

I am trying to implement animations in my android app. I have 2 activities in it.

`Activity_1` has 3 images, namely `img1`, `img2`, `img3`. This is what it looks like -

**Activity_1**

[image]

Now, when the user presses `img1`, I want to display `img1` in `Activity_2` or `the same activity i.e. Activity_1`(if possible) using the animation in this site : http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html

**Activity_2**

[image]

The above mentioned site (http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html) explains how to animate the image, but the background or the activity is shown. So, how do I use that animation on `img1` while shifting it to the left side of the screen as seen in the above mentioned on click? and how do I get rid of the `TextView (Activity_1)` and the images `(img2, img3)` and display info about `img1` Please help me out with the code. Thanks in advance!